# DbContext not getting inteliisense for SaveChanges()

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I am using Entity Framework 6.0.2 and Oracle 11g.

I am trying to Add,Update and Delete objects using entity framework.

I am not getting intellisense for SaveChanges(),Remove(),Add() methods.

What references are required to get these.
I have added the following in packages.config.
here is my package.Config.

```
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="odp.net.x64" version="112.3.20" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Oracle.DataAccess.x86" version="2.112.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" version="12.1.021" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework" version="12.1.021" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Here is my DbContext.

```
 public class OLADBContext:DbContext,IOLADBContext
    {
         protected static string m_connectionString = "";
        public static OLADBContext Create()
        {

            ConnectionStringSettings dbSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleDbContext"];
                if (dbSettings != null)
                {
                        m_connectionString =  dbSettings.ConnectionString;
                 }


            return new OLADBContext(m_connectionString);
        }

        public OLADBContext(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {
        }



        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("HRMS2");
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EmployeeMapper());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EmpAuthMapper());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SpecialPrivilegesMapper());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProbationDetailsMapper());
                        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }


        public DbSet<Employee> Employes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EmpAuthentication> Authentication { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SpecialPrivileges> SpecialPrivilege { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProbationDetails> ProbationDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

here is my code:

```
     public void CheckEmployeeExists(string EmpId)
            {
                var userType="N";
                var authenticationDetails = _olaDbContext.Authentication.Where(a => a.IsEnabled == "Y" && a.EmployeeId == EmpId).FirstOrDefault();

                if (authenticationDetails == null)
                {                
                    var emp = _olaDbContext.Employes.Where(e=>e.EmployeeId==EmpId).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (emp != null)
                    {
                        if (emp.IsManager == "Y")
                            userType = "T";
                        else if (emp.Designation.ToUpper().Contains("HR EXEC") || emp.Designation_Id == 447)
                        {
                            userType = "H";
                        }
                        else if (emp.Designation.Contains("Time Office"))
                        {
                            userType = "A";
                        }

                        var probationDetails = _olaDbContext.ProbationDetails.Where(p => p.EmployeeId == EmpId);
                        ProbationDetails oprob = new ProbationDetails();
                        oprob.EmployeeId = "16785";
                        oprob.ProbatoionPeriod = 3;
                        _olaDbContext.ProbationDetails.Add(oprob);
    }
    }
}
```

Please let me know how can i acheive?

Comment: Where did you expect to get intellisense?

Comment: Like when I tried to do this,I am not getting intellisense.                       var probationDetails = _olaDbContext.ProbationDetails.Where(p => p.EmployeeId == EmpId);
                    
_olaDbContext.SaveChanges();

Comment: Please edit your question to show this code (and the usings).

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed.

I am doing the mistake instead of referencing the OLADbConext  directly I am referencing the IOLADbContext in my class

```
    public class OLADBContext:DbContext,IOLADBContext
        {
}
```

i have commented the code referencing the interface and used directly the class

```
 public class OLADataProvider:IOLADataProvider
    {
       // private IOLADBContext _olaDbContext;
            private OLADBContext _olaDbContext;

        public OLADataProvider(OLADBContext olaDbContext)
        {
            if (olaDbContext == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("olaDbContext is Null");
            //_olaDbContext = olaDbContext;
                        _olaDbContext = olaDbContext;
        }
```